# What commands/config can I use to deploy a django+postgres+nginx using ecs-cli?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a basic django/postgres app running locally, based on [the Docker Django docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). It uses docker compose to run the containers locally.

I'd like to run this app on Amazon Web Services (AWS), and to deploy it using the command line, not the AWS console.

### My Attempt

When I tried this, I ended up with:

- [this yml config for ecs-cli](https://github.com/trailbehind/DeepOSM/blob/03cfdab768d7e625cfbe3838b50674e35660af8e/deeposm_org/deeposm-prod.yml)
- these [notes on how I deployed from the command line](https://github.com/trailbehind/DeepOSM/blob/03cfdab768d7e625cfbe3838b50674e35660af8e/deeposm_org/README.md).

Note: I was trying to fire up the Python dev server in a janky way, hoping that would work before I added nginx. The cluster (RDS+server) would come up, but then the instances would die right away.

### Issues I Then Failed to Solve

I realized over the course of this:

- the setup needs another container for a web server (nginx) to run on AWS ([like this blog post](http://pritishc.com/blog/2015/09/03/docker-is-awesome/), but the tutorial uses the AWS Console, which I wanted to avoid)
- ecs-cli uses a different syntax for yml/json config than docker-compose, so you need to have some separate/similar code from your local docker.yml (and I'm not sure if my file above was correct)

### Question

So, what ecs-cli commands and config do I use to deploy the app, or am I going about things all wrong?

Feel free to say I'm doing it all wrong. I could also use Elastic Beanstalk - [the tutorials on this don't seem to use docker/docker-compose](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/), but seem easier overall (at least well documented).

I'd like to understand why any given approach is a good way to do this.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative you may wish to consider in lieu of ECS, if you just want to get it up in the amazon cloud, is to make use of docker-machine using the [amazonec2](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/) driver.

When executing the docker-compose, just ensure the remote Amazon host machine is **ACTIVE** which can be viewed with a `docker-machine ls`

One item you will have to revisit with the Amazon Mmgt Console is to open the applicable PORTS such as Port 80 and any other ports exposed in the compose file. Once the security group is in place for the VPC, you should be able to simply refer to the VPC ID on subsequent executions bypassing any need to use the Mgmt console to add the ports. You may wish to bump up the instance size from the default `t2.micro` to match the `t2.medium` specified in your NOTES.

---

If ECS *orchestration* is needed, then a task definition will need to be created containing the container definitions you require as defined in your docker compose file. My recommendation would be to take advantage of the Mgmt console to construct the definition and then grab the accompanying JSON defintion which is made available and store in your source code repository for future executions on the command line where they can be referenced in registering task definitions, executing tasks and services within a given cluster.